# Evidence of magnesium supplements for chronic fatigue?

Tags: fatigue, magnesium, supplement

I was working on a statistic problem about a trial where researchers tested magnesium on individuals with chronic fatigue to see if it would help. I wasn't sure if it was hypothetical or based on a real experiment, so I'm wondering if there's any evidence that magnesium intake can alleviate, treat, or lessen chronic fatigue? More detail on magnesium would be great.

Comment: This question may fit better in Skeptics.SE.

Comment: I think it's fine for Health, in part because the claim isn't necessarily notable - at least, it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is at least one study on this, published in *The Lancet*:

[Red blood cell magnesium and chronic fatigue syndrome](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/014067369191371Z)

> Patients treated with magnesium claimed to have improved energy levels, better emotional state, and less pain, as judged by changes in the Nottingham health profile.

This was a trial on only 20 patients with CSF and 20 control patients. That size of course isn't large enough to draw any reliable conclusions.

I also found a study comparing magnesium levels in patients with CSF with healthy controls that found [no difference in magnesium levels](http://m.acb.sagepub.com/content/31/5/459.short).

The [University of Maryland Medical Center summarizes](https://umm.edu/health/medical/altmed/condition/chronic-fatigue-syndrome):

> Magnesium (300 to 1,000 mg per day) may help reduce fatigue. But studies show mixed results.